# Pandas: order legends (or columns) by a register value order

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

After a lot of manipulations, I arrived to a simple dataframe where each register line is an year and each column a line I want to put in line plot. Something like:

```
year  line1  line2  line3
2000  10     20     30
2001  15     12     29
2002  19     13     24
```

When the legends are displayed, I'd like to have them ordered in the same order of the last register values. That is:

1. line3
2. line1
3. line2

In the line graph, the bigger value will be on top, so I'd like to have my legends mapping the display of the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
reg.sort_values(reg.index[-1], axis=1, ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

where the first parameter is the desired register order, and the axis tells that I want the columns ordered. See that this is reordering the columns. Your dataframe would now be this one:

```
year  line3  line1  line2  
2000  30     10     20     
2001  29     15     12     
2002  24     19     13
```

Comment: So is this question fully answered?  Or were you looking for something further?

Comment: @pshep123:I got what I think is a nice solution and decided to share here. I'm always open to choose better answers.